# How do I send out of etherscan

Tags: ether

I sold zrx in binance and sent it to my ethereum address in coinbase. My coinbase account was blocked so when I went back to binance at the bottom I clicked and it showed the sale with the money sitting in etherscan.  How do I get the money out with a new digital address back to binance and buy eth there

Comment: Since the address was generated by Coinbase you have to ask their support, you cannot (in practice) reverse a transaction already confirmed in the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan is simply a tool which visualizes data on the Ethereum blockchain. It does not actually represent a wallet/storage service of any kind.

Etherscan is showing you that your funds are located at a specific Ethereum Address, and you will need access to that address in order to transfer the funds again.

Unfortunately, if you sent your funds to your Coinbase wallet, then the funds are likely in their control or lost to the system. See the warning they show below:

[image]

In the future, you should make sure to always send Ethereum Tokens to a personal Ethereum wallet, or to an exchange wallet specifically made for that token.